# How to mock a function in an unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nmock

How could I unittest GetData by NMock3?

It would be great if prcessA.Run and the "result" inside ProcessA could be mocked.

IAnotherService could not be GetData's parameter as it depends on a processed value inside GetData.

Any ideas?

**Service1**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1()
    {
    }

    public string GetData(int a)
    {
        // some process depends on input
        int b = a * new Random().Next();

        IAnotherService anotherService = new AnotherService(b);
        ProcessA processA = new ProcessA(anotherService);
        processA.Run();
        return processA.result;
    }
}
```

**Simplified ProcessA**

```
public class ProcessA
{
    public string result;
    private IAnotherService anotherService;

    public ProcessA(IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        this.anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Some other process here
        this.result = this.anotherService.Run();
    }
}
```

**TestMethod1**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (mockFactory.Ordered())
    {
        // Nothing to Mock
    }

    IService1 service1 = new Service1();
    string aaa = service1.GetData(1);

    Assert.AreEqual("XXX", aaa);
}
```

Comment: You need to mock out out the services and inject those into their dependent classes. So mock IAnotherService and pass that into the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, you need to mock out the dependent services and set up what you are expecting to return.

I've done a test below and it works. I use Moq, but the principal is the same.

```
 public interface IAnotherService
 {
     string Run();
 }

public class ProcessA
{
    public string result;
    private readonly IAnotherService _anotherService;

    public ProcessA(IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        this._anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public string Run()
    {
        // Some other process here
        return _anotherService.Run();
    }   
}
```

Then run the test

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   //Create a Mock
   var mockService = new Mock<IAnotherService>();
   //Set the expected result
   mockService.Setup(method => method.Run()).Returns("XXX");

   //Inject the mock
   var process = new ProcessA(mockService.Object);
   var result = process.Run();

   //Assert the result     
   Assert.AreEqual("XXX", result);
}
```

EDIT

As discussed, I've edited my answer to hopefuly what you need.

```
 public interface IService1
    {
        string GetData(int a);
        int ValueForB { get; set; }
    }

public class Service1Consumer : IService1
{
    private readonly IAnotherService _anotherServiceImplementation;

    public Service1Consumer(IAnotherService service)
    {
        _anotherServiceImplementation = service;
    }

    public string GetData(int a)
    {
        ValueForB = a * new Random().Next();
        _anotherServiceImplementation.ValueFor = b;
        var processA = new ProcessA(_anotherServiceImplementation);
        return processA.Run();
    }
}

public interface IAnotherService
{
    int ValueForB { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherService : IAnotherService
{
}

public class ProcessA
{
    public string result;
    private readonly IAnotherService _anotherService;

    public ProcessA(IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        _anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public string Run()
    {
        return "XXXX";
    }
}
```

Then the test.

```
  [Test]
  public void TestMethod1()
  {
      //Create a Mock
      var mockAnotherService = new Mock<IAnotherService>();
      //Set the property value when called.
      mockAnotherService.Setup(method => method.ValueForB).Returns(10);//Test 1

      var service1Consumer = new Service1Consumer(mockAnotherService.Object);
      var result = service1Consumer.GetData();

      Assert.AreEqual("XXXX",result);

   }
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: @Rainbolt - ha ha. yes.. I'm using Moq. They are very similar aren't they. forget he was using NMoq3. Hopefuly OP will get the gist of things.

Comment: @Rainbolt - True...  I've made a comment to that affect anyway. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for your comments.

Comment: Infact I would like to unittest GetData's flow, not ProcessA.Run only.
May be my example is too simple. The real case is more complicated as below
How to mock processA, processB, processC in the unittest of GetData?

Comment: public string GetData(int a)
    {
  string result;
 
        int b = a+1;  // Simplfied Get B from A

        IAnotherService anotherService = new AnotherService(b);
  IAnotherService2 anotherService2 = new AnotherService2(b);
        ProcessA processA = new ProcessA(anotherService);
        string resulOfProcessA = processA.Run();
  
  if (resulOfProcessA == "B")
  {
   ProcessB processB = new ProcessB();
   result = processB.Run();
  } else {
      ProcessC processC = new ProcessC(anotherService2);
   result = processC.Run();
  }
  
  return result;
    }

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetDataWithProcessBRun()
        {
   using (mockFactory.Ordered())
            {
              // How to mock processA, processB here?
            }
  
            IService1 service1 = new Service1();
            string aaa = service1.GetData(1); // Assume input 1 will get "B" for resulOfProcessA
      
            Assert.AreEqual("ResultOfB", aaa);   
        }

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetDataWithProcessCRun()
        {
   using (mockFactory.Ordered())
            {
              // How to mock processA, processC here?
            }
  
            IService1 service1 = new Service1();
            string aaa = service1.GetData(2); // Assume input 2 will get "C" for resulOfProcessA

            Assert.AreEqual("ResultOfC", aaa);   
        }

Comment: If you want to Mock "GetData", then you need to create a mock of IService1 and inject that into whatever class consumes it. But IService1 depends upon IAnotherService and so you would need to mock this as well and inject it into IService1 before you inject it into its consuming class.

Comment: That's the problem. I am not sure how to inject the IAnotherService to the constructor of Service1
as the instant implementation of IAnotherService depends on parameter b which is a process result of parameter a of GetData.
In constructor if Service1, a is unknown, so b could not be calculated, IAnotherService could not be injected.

Any other way to inject?
Thanks.

Comment: @mintssoul - Ok.. but I assume parameter "b" only has a certain number of values? Even if not, you don't have to test all permutations. Create a number of tests where b is a certain value and test that scenario specifically. You can call those unit tests something like "Call_GetData_With_b_Equals_X_Returns_MyResult" so its obvious what you are testing.

Comment: Sorry, I am not so good at unittest so still not understand how to mock processA/B but I am testing GetData.  Since there is no injection through constructor of GetData, I could pass mock object processA or processB which is inside GetData (And processA must be mocked as it is currency related and the result is different from time to time).  Could you give me an example similar to the code below? Thank you very much.

Comment: [TestMethod]

public void TestGetDataWithProcessBRun() {

using (mockFactory.Ordered()) {
// How to mock processA, processB here?
}

IService1 service1 = new Service1();
string aaa = service1.GetData(1); // Assume input 1 will get "B" for resulOfProcessA Assert.AreEqual("ResultOfB", aaa);
}

Comment: @mintssoul - Hello. I've updated my answer to show you how you can achieve this. Remember its fine to change the design of your classes to help make your tests work. I've spent more time than usual on this, so you'll have to take it from here. Good luck.

Comment: The Value of B can only be calculated in GetData(int a) because it is depends on input 'a'.
So the ValueOfB could not be set outside in my consumption program.

In consumption,
IService1 service1 = new Service1Consumer(new AnotherService(b));
string aaa = service1.GetData(10);

The 'b' in constructor of Service1Consumer is yet unknown
and it should be calculated using the parameter of GetData '10' to get 'b'
So how to do this?

Comment: @mintssoul - as mentioned previously. If you can't test your design then you probably need to change it! I'd remove the constructor for "b" on IAnotherService and expose a property.